# instead of date% I have to use $date% in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am using

```
SELECT * FROM appointment 
WHERE AptDateTime Like '2015-07-22%' 
ORDER BY AptDateTime DESC
```

and it is working fine,

But instead of `2015-07-22%` I have to use variable `$date%`  in Mysql in order to make it dynamic.

Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Comment: What's your current progress on writing the PHP code? Please edit the question and include the PHP code that is relevant.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE AptDateTime Like '$date%' ORDER BY AptDateTime DESC"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query pass variable in your query like that `'$date%'` :-

```
"SELECT * FROM appointment 
WHERE AptDateTime Like '$date%'
ORDER BY AptDateTime DESC";
```